# If three columns exactly match then return value by using countifs condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I'm working on countifs condition where all 3 columns matches then it will return total count. I've attached screenshot for reference.

As per image you can see that in column D "Total VM" formula used, I'm counting total VM on basis of 3 columns "A","B","C" matches with column "O","P","Q".

Formula used

```
=index(countifs(N:N,"*WinOs*",match(1,(A2=Q:Q)*(B2=O:O)*(C2=P:P),0),1))
```

Please guide me to correct the formula.

[image]

Comment: If you want to count how many rows meet `WinOs` and their host, serial and cluster values are same than A,B and C, you just need COUNTIFS. Something like `COUNTIFS(N:N;"*WinOs*";O:O;B2;P:P;C2;Q:Q;A2) should work`. Also, consider using Pivot Table to resume your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count how many rows meet WinOs and their host, serial and cluster values are same than A,B and C, you just need COUNTIFS.

Something like `COUNTIFS(N:N;"*WinOs*";O:O;B2;P:P;C2;Q:Q;A2)` should work.

Also, consider using Pivot Table to resume your data.